# haskell error change user input to user defined data type in function

Tags: haskell, logic, haskell-lens

```
handleStatements :: [Term] -> IO ()
handleStatements statements = do
    let (queries, clauses) = partition isQuery statements
    mapM_ (clausesEntailProof clauses) queries
    --apply clauses to queries and ignore result

handleArgs :: String-> IO ()
handleArgs args = do
    contents <- readFile $ args
    case parseInput contents of
      Left err -> print err
      Right statements -> handleStatements statements


main :: IO ()
main = do
  handleStatements(input)
    where input = getLine >>= (\str -> ((readIO str)::IO[Term]))
```

I got error.
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Term]’ with actual type ‘IO Term’. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can not use a `where` like this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ...why not? Looks perfectly cromulent to me. Just misses a `>>=` in the body (as in `input >>= handleStatements`).

Comment: @DanielWagner: Yes, but the question seems to indicate that `where` somehow performs the `IO` and then sets the *result* to `input`. You can indeed use `input >>= handleStatements`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah, I see. It seems "this" could refer to quite a lot of things when there's no antecedent. How confusing! Thanks for clarifying what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `input = …` in the `where` clause, then `input` has type `IO [Term]`, not `[Term]`, so you can not pass `input` to the `handleStatement`s.

You can write:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- getLine >>= (\str -> ((readIO str)::IO[Term]))
    handleStatements input
```

But you are making things too complicated, you can work with [**`readLn :: Read a => IO a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn) instead:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- readLn
    handleStatements input
```

or replace the do block with the [**`(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`** function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-):

```
main :: IO ()
main = readLn >>= handleStatements
```

Comment: Thankyou!! i have another question, if i have for example [A->C,B->Q,A+D,?(C+Q)] this input. I got error *** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse) , should i change it to list?

Comment: @kili: you are already parsing a `[Term]`, so likely it means your parser for a single `Term`, can not handle one of the `A->C`, `B->Q`, `A+D`, etc. or it does not stop at the comma.

Comment: Thankyou if i want to parse it in list according to the coma , is there way to do this? or the only way is from reading file and parse it?